# Calculate difference in hours between two datetime values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datediff

I'm working on a query that deals with the details behind a series of electronic documents. Each document has a `CreateDate` and a `CompletedDate`, both of which are in **datetime** format. My goal is to calculate the number of hours that elapse between these two dates.

```
SELECT
DocID,
CreateDate,
CompletedDate,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),DATEDIFF(HOUR,CreateDate,CompletedDate)) AS DiffHours

FROM Documents
```

It's a simple query, and it works perfectly fine. However, I end up with results like this:

```
DocID   CreateDate                  CompletedDate               DiffHours
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
0001    2021-07-01 08:34:28.130     2021-07-01 08:58:14.633     0.00
0002    2021-07-01 10:33:03.157     2021-07-02 08:37:14.120     22.00
```

The conversion to decimal technically works, but it's still only displaying the `DiffHours` result as a rounded number. For example, for that first document with ID 0001, a full hour hasn't elapsed between the two times, but I still would have expected the result to show as `0.42` or so rather than rounding down to 0. Likewise, I would have expected the second document to show as `22.[something]` rather than just the flat `22.00`.

Is there a way to force the calculation to be more exact? Again, technically the query works the way it is, but if I can't display the correct fraction of the hour, then it's not going to be as useful as I'd like it to be.

Comment: The answers don't mention the fact that datediff counts the boundaries between two dates e.g. `2020-01-01 00:59:59` and `2020-01-01 01:00:00` are one second apart but datediff(hour, ...) says they are one hour apart.

Comment: @SalmanA ahh, that makes sense

Comment: @SalmanA that's true when calculaing the difference in hours, but neither answer does that; you could also have datetimes either side of midnight separated by seconds and datediff measured in *days* will also result in 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for greater accuracy you need to use higher precision values, eg the difference in seconds.

For example

```
declare @createdate datetime='20210701 08:34:28.130', @CompletedDate datetime='20210701 08:58:14.633'

select Convert(decimal(15,2),DateDiff(second, @createdate,@completeddate)/60.0/60.0)
select Convert(decimal(15,4),DateDiff(second, @createdate,@completeddate)/60.0/60.0)
```

**Output**

> 0.40

> 0.3961

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the delta in `MINUTES` and then convert into hours by dividing by 60.

Note the **`60.0`** ... this will prevent integer division which will return an integer.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([DocID] varchar(50),[CreateDate] datetime,[CompletedDate] datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('0001','2021-07-01 08:34:28.130','2021-07-01 08:58:14.633')
,('0002','2021-07-01 10:33:03.157','2021-07-02 08:37:14.120')
 
Select * 
      ,Diff = convert(decimal(15,2),datediff(MINUTE,[CreateDate],[CompletedDate]) / 60.0)
from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
DocID   CreateDate              CompletedDate            Diff
0001    2021-07-01 08:34:28.130 2021-07-01 08:58:14.633  0.40
0002    2021-07-01 10:33:03.157 2021-07-02 08:37:14.120  22.07
```